# MVC - Manually set form submit value from ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In a web app I'm creating, I have a list of clients. And each client has a sub-list of projects.

This is my Client model:

```
Public Class ppClient
    <Key()>
    Public Property ClientID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overridable Property Projects As ICollection(Of ppProject)
End Class
```

And here is my Project model:

```
Public Class ppProject
    <Key()>
    Public Property ProjectID As Integer
    Public Property ClientID As Integer
    Public Property ProjectTitle As String

    Public Overridable Property Client As ppClient
End Class
```

The problem I am encountering is that I am trying to manually add a form value when a new project is being created. I have the ClientID saved in ViewData, and so I don't want to ask the user for it. This is my view and form submission:

```
ModelType MVCnewDB.ppProject

@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)

    @* Needs to submit ClientID *@

    Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.ProjectTitle)
    Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ProjectTitle)
    @<input type="submit" value="Create Project" />
End Using

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index")
</div>
```

So how do I get the form to submit ClientID as my ViewData value? Can I make a call to `Html.HiddenFor` and stuff a value into it or something?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not *quite* sure what is being asked, but if the `ClientID` is generated (or stored) on the server, I think a better approach would be to keep it server-side - generate or retrieve it in the Action that responds to the POST, rather than sending it to the client (and trusting that the value you get back from the client hasn't been tampered with for whatever reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah okay - I've found what I was looking for. I was looking for `@Html.Hidden("ClientID", ViewData("key"))` which submits the given ViewData value to the form as the ClientID field.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a hidden field.  I don't know how you would do it in VB, but in C# it would be like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => ViewBag.ClientID)
```

or

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => ViewData["ClientID"])
```

Comment: When creating a project though, only ProjectID is auto-generated. I need to set the value of ClientID, which the creation of a hidden field doesn't do.

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot - You're contradicting yourself.  You said you already had this value created.

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot - You need to be a lot more specific, because apparently what you're asking for and what you want are two different things.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have the ClientID I want in ViewData. I just didn't know how to make the form access and submit that value. It looks like @Html.Hidden was what I was looking for, see below.

Comment: No, I don't think this is the same. I just tried your code - this doesn't submit a value to the form as the "ClientID" field. It throws a "Insert statement conflicted with foreign key constraint... column ClientID" because it wasn't submitted.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I interpret your question:

- You are on a page with a model bound to your ppProject class
- You have a ClientID somewhere and you want to know where to put it on the form so that...
- You want the form submission to include the ClientID so you can relate the ppProject to a client.

Is this correct?

If so, you have a couple options. If you've included your ClientID in a ViewBag, you can use a hidden field to store the value and submit it. On your action, you can actually specify more than one parameter. The first can be the ppProject class you want the model binder to bind your fields to, and another string parameter with **the same name** as the hidden field containing your ClientID value. As long as the parameter matches the hidden field name exactly, the model binder will match the two up and you'll get the ClientID.

(In C# because my VB.NET skills are too rusty for it to make sense:)

```
public ActionResult NewProject(ppProject projectInfo, string ClientID)
{
  ...
}
```

The above assumes you keep your view as-is but you add something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ClientID" value="@ViewBag.ClientID" />
```

Or possibly (just a guess!):

```
Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) ViewBag.ClientID)
```

This assumes you've matched the ViewBag property name to the parameter name on your ActionResult in your controller. (Just replace the ViewBag with whatever you're using to store the ClientID value.)